# JQuery not returning div in IE, but Firefox/Chrome/Safari is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following code in the html:

```
<div id="image-internal">
```

The I have the following code in my javascript:

```
parent = $("#" + type + "-" + location);
parent.empty();
```

parent.empty() in IE only, is returning a JavaScript error, saying "Object doesn't support property or method 'empty'.  All other browsers (FireFox/Chrome/Safari) correctly set parent to the div object and allow the empty() call.

What can be causing IE to behave this way? and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you use `alert("#" + type + "-" + location)` , do you see what you expect? Maybe a conflict with window.location

Comment: Test the value of the string you are constructing, and note that `location` is a browser variable … IE might not like you trying to mask it.

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? 2.0+ isn't supported by oldIE

Comment: @Dr.Molle I see #image-internal that is what I expect.  Quentin I changed all my locations to loc just in case but I still have the same problem.  yckart I am using jQuery 1.2.4a

Comment: did you change `parent` to like `myparent` or something?

Comment: jQuery 1.2? That's ancient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the name of the variable or define it using the `var`-keyword. `parent` is a built-in property of `window` .